# Colab Notebook: Cannot import name 'container_abcs' from 'torch._six'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run the deit colab notebook found here:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/facebookresearch/deit/blob/colab/notebooks/deit_inference.ipynb

but I'm running into an issue in the second cell, specifically the `import timm` line, which returns this:

ImportError: cannot import name 'container_abcs' from 'torch._six'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Issue related to this error [here](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch/issues/424):

Try a specific *version* of `timm` library:

```
!pip install timm==0.3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

when I install torch==1.9.0 and torch-geometric,
the old code has the errors.

here is my solution:

```
   TORCH_MAJOR = int(torch.__version__.split('.')[0])
   TORCH_MINOR = int(torch.__version__.split('.')[1])
   if TORCH_MAJOR == 0:
      import collections.abc as container_abcs
   else:
      from torch._six import container_abcs
```

change to：

```
    TORCH_MAJOR = int(torch.__version__.split('.')[0])
    TORCH_MINOR = int(torch.__version__.split('.')[1])
    if TORCH_MAJOR == 1 and TORCH_MINOR < 8:
        from torch._six import container_abcs,int_classes
    else:
        import collections.abc as container_abcs
        int_classes = int
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked with

```
pip install timm==0.4.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I was working on PyTorch 1.12 version with a code base developed on PyTorch 1.6.

You should replace

```
from torch._six import container_abcs
```

with

```
import container.abc as container_abcs
```

as per [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/1048).